# How to output a pattern without including the beginning of the pattern?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle-sqldeveloper, regex-group

I am trying to extract two characters from CLOB in Orcale. For example, the CLOB column looks like this:

`"rateArea":"KCMO","state":"MO","addressComponent":null,"msag":null`

I wrote:

```
 SELECT
 REGEXP_SUBSTR( ORD_DETAILS,  'state":"+\w\w' ) state
 from order_log
```

This gives me the output - `state":"MO`

I just want `MO` as my output.

Can you please suggest the regex code for the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a capture group. `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` takes an optional parameter to specify which group to extract instead ot the whole match.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( ORD_DETAILS,  'state":"+(\w\w)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) state
FROM order_log
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is very similar to JSON, and if your Oracle database version is 12c or higher, you can try using the [`JSON_TABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions092.htm#SQLRF56973) function:

```
SELECT jt.state
FROM order_log ol
CROSS JOIN json_table(
  '{'||ol.ord_details||'}', '$'
  COLUMNS (
    rate_area VARCHAR2(30) PATH '$.rateArea',
    state VARCHAR2(5) PATH '$.state',
    addr_comp VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.addressComponent',
    msag VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.msag'
  )
) jt;
```

**Output:**

```
STATE
-----
MO
```

Test it online with [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=366b18c91fa90e2d16c048fca68f0c43).